# Ruby bundles, .bat, and Inno Installer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, batch-file, inno-setup

I'm trying to do a bunch of changes to a client's legacy product. It's a Ruby on Rails app with a heavyweight Java applet embedded in the page. I've solved concurrency issues in the applet, I've implemented unimplemented functionality in the Rails app, but I am absolutely being stymied by an Inno Software installer.

The specific problem is that part of the installer calls the bundler through a simple BAT file.  The important command is

```
bundle install --deployment --local --verbose
```

I can tell it's important because the BAT file runs just fine from the command line or explorer, but fails -- silently! -- when it's run by the installer.

I'm more or less at wit's end. I've got echos and logging and all that.

Is there something I'm missing that makes a BAT file execute differently in the installer context?

**Update**

Thanks for the link to that other question, but I've already tried the install with a setup to keep the window open, and I have debugging echos in it.  But the problem appears to be that the `bundle` command itself is working differently in the context of the installer than in command-line context.

Comment: I suppose you verified that there are no PAUSEs in the bat file and no place where it is expecting operator response?

Comment: Yes on the no-pauses.

Comment: Did you try the command on elevated command-prompt (to make the test close to the installer environment)?

Comment: No, what do you mean by "elevated command-prompt"

Comment: `cmd.exe` run "As Administrator"